# ¿Como asignar suficiente memoria para n char sin escribir la cadena completa?

Tags: string, powershell, manejo-de-memoria

Estuve jugando un poco con powershell y me encontré con esta pregunta al hacer un programa que imite la pantalla llena de número del programa Matrix:

```
while (1){
$num=""
for ($i=0;$i -lt 80;$i++){
    $r=Get-Random -Maximum 9
    $num+=$r.ToString()
}
echo $num
}
```

Para hacerlo tuve que crear una cadena vacía he ir agrandándola con cada concatenación, pero a mí me gustaría en vez de agrandarla concatenando, determinar de una vez el tamaño total de la cadena, he ir modificando char a char el número, así como se haría en C(`char* cadena=(char*)malloc(80);`), para así aumentar la velocidad de mi programa, ¿cómo lo hago?.

Este fue mi intento:

```
$num=""[0..80]
while (1){
for ($i=0;$i -lt 80;$i++){
    $r=Get-Random -Maximum 9
    $num[$i]=[char]([int]'0')+$r
}
echo $num
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
}
```

Este es mi mensaje de error:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At line:5 char:5
+     $num[$i]=[char]([int]'0')+$r
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], IndexOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PowerShell se basa en .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR).](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.3)

Lo que te habilita a reescribir tu código como:

```
for ($i=0;$i -lt $num.Length; $i++){
    $r=Get-Random -Maximum 9
    $num[$i]=[char]([int]'0')+$r
}
```

Si imprimes la longitud del arreglo verás que es 0.

El problema está en que `""` es una cadena vacía. 0 por cualquier número es 0. La longitud de la cadena entonces es 0.

Moraleja: no confíes en tu intuición. Confía en lo que la propiedad `Length` te dice.

---

Una mejor forma de crear arreglos es multiplicando por el número de elementos que quieres que tenga.

Así:

```
$a = ' ' * 80
```

Por último, multiplicar una cadena en Powershell, en realidad genera un `String`.

En .NET este tipo es inmutable. Así que para obtener un arreglo de caracteres puedes usar la función [`ToCharArray`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083216/13419694):

```
$a = (' ' * 80).ToCharArray()
```

---

Otra forma de hacerlo es instanciando un arreglo de caracteres. Al igual que en C#, se pueden instanciar las clases. Podes hacerlo mediante el cmdlet [`New-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083216/13419694):

```
$a = New-Object char[] 80
```

Comment: Lo malo es que ahora echo imprime todos los caracteres con saltos de lineas y no pegado.

Comment: Mateo, para que mejores tu respuesta. Antes de llegar al echo utilizas el metodo joint en otra variable para obtener la cadena y despues mostrarla por echo: $b=-join $num;echo $b;  y asi evitar que se generen saltos de lineas

Comment: @Daniel creo que escapa un poco de la pregunta. Otra forma es llamar al constructor de string que toma un `char[]`: `New-Object String $a` o puedes cambiar la variable `$ofs` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12752430/13419694